# Tips for approaching simple problems

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm rather new to higher math problems including proofs etc.
I've now got a problem in front of me which I cannot wrap my head around on how to approach it:

$(a,b)$ can be defined as the subset $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\} \subseteq P(A \cup B)$.

Show:

For $a, a' \in A$ and $b, b' \in B$ holds:

$(a, b) = (a', b') \leftrightarrow a = a'$ and $b = b'$

I simply don't even really know where to start here. Do you have any tips/ resources on how to apporach these kind of problems?

Comment: (1) Do you understand the definition?  (2) to prove a $\Leftrightarrow$ do it in two parts, one $\Leftarrow$ and one $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: I don't quite get what is meant with the definition or how it would help me with the problem, no.

Comment: So, if you do not understand the definition, then work out some examples.  What is $(1,2)$?  What is $(2,1)$?  Wha is $(3,3)$?